# Copy data from S3 file into aws postgresql: invalid argument?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am trying to copy the content of an AWS S3 file into a AWS RDS Postgresql table but seem to get my syntax wrong?

COPY myschema.mytable 
  FROM 'S3://bucket-name/file_name.csv' (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER E'\t', ENCODING 'utf-8');

returns the following error:  ERROR: could not open file "S3://bucket-name/file_name.csv" for reading: Invalid argument

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Postgresql [COPY command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html) does not support copying data from S3.  You'll need to use an intermediate service to download the data from S3 and then upload them to the database.

This doc will help you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

This tutorial shows how to use Data Pipeline to move data between S3 and RDS MySQL.  Should be fairly similar for Postgress. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-copys3tords.html